# How can I make a grading scale more objective?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, scales

I want to come up with an at least slightly more objective scale than the one found here: https://www.profootballfocus.com/about/how-we-grade/

In the link, each play for each football player is graded on a scale of -2 to 2 with 0.5 point increments, leaving room for a lot of subjectivity.

I thought about using only two grades (0 = negative and 1 = positive), but what is the way to make the grading scale as objective as possible?

Comment: Do you have the resources to evaluate **every** play in the NFL? That's what is being done by the guys in the link you provided. I may not be understanding something but the framework laid out there seems pretty rigorous. What they neither mention nor report is the *interrater* reliability between the steps. In other words, how much do these guys agree on the ratings? This is the key piece of information missing that would enable a more objective evaluation of the success of their methodology. Why do you want to "improve" this?

Comment: Yes, I do have the resources to evaluate every play, just not as time efficiently as they probably can. I want to improve it because I feel like they are just watching film and combining that into a number with a decimal point to make it seem objective, when it's really not.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult for many positions in football. Let's say you have a defensive linesman. What is a high score? Does he get a high score only if gets through the offensive line? What if he makes a tackle on the RB? Which of these gets a higher score? It's subjective and/or based around the situation and analyzing every play from the perspective of every player would be time-consuming.

One way to do that is really simple (But purely objective) is to grant every player on the defense a score based on how many yards the offense got (and just score the offense for yards).

E.g.
Offense loses 5 yards. Every player on offense gets -5, every player on defense gets 15.
Incomplete Pass. Offense gets +0, defense gets 10.
Offense gains 10. Offense gets 10, defense gets 0
Offense gains 40. Offense gets 40, defense gets -30.

It's a stupid system that won't tell you much about individual contribution, but it's objective. You might want to move the numbers around (i.e. offense only gets +5 when they gain 10 yards or whatever).

Comment: This is something I would definitely consider for evaluating units as a whole, and I could adapt it on a more granular level for individual players, or?